# Let $G$ be a $p$-group: $|G| = p^r$. Prove that $G$ contains a normal subgroup of order $p^k$ for every nonnegative $k \le r$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups, fake-proofs

> Let $p$ be a prime number, and let $G$ be a $p$-group: $|G| = p^r$. Prove that $G$ contains a normal subgroup of order $p^k$ for every nonnegative $k \le r$.

The answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549635/a-p-group-of-order-pn-has-a-normal-subgroup-of-order-pk-for-each-0-le-k) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1788345/p-groups-have-normal-subgroups-of-each-order?noredirect=1&lq=1) use induction but they assume $G$, where $|G|=p^r$, has normal subgroups of order $p^k$ for $k <r$. Induction should start by assuming for every $p$-group of order $p^k$ where $0\le k <r$, there exists normal subgroups of order $p^i$ where $0 \le i \le k$.

We have to show there exists normal subgroups of order $p^i$ where $0 \le i \le r$.

Comment: Figure out your own solution then. My suggestion: use induction and the fact that $p$-groups have non-trivial centres. (The induction would be on $r$, so for $s<r$ the inductive hypothesis will give you that a $p$-group of order $p^s$ has normal subgroups of each possible order.)

Comment: @the_fox That's exactly what I wrote.

Comment: Do you want me to comment on the other "solutions" or how to give a proof?

Comment: Actually, you haven't asked anything.

Comment: @the_fox I'm interested in knowing how to go about solving this.

Comment: Let me give a concrete example (it's not a proof). Say you have $G$ with $|G|=p^5$ and that the claim holds for $p$-groups of order $p^4$. Take $N$ to be a subgroup of the centre of $G$ of order $p$. Look at $G/N$. It has normal subgroups of order $1, p, p^2, p^3, p^4$.

Comment: If the above makes sense to you, you can easily turn it into a proper proof. If there's a sticky point somewhere, let me know.

Comment: @the_fox I think I got it. Would you mind if I post the solution?

Comment: Not at all. Go ahead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If $|G|=p^0=1$, then vacuous. If $|G|=p$, then $\{1\}$ and $G$ are normal subgroups of order $p^0$ and $p^1$.

Suppose the statement is true for $p$-groups of order $p^k$ where $k < r$. Let $|G|=p^r$.

Since $G$ is a $p$-group, it has a non-trivial center, $Z(G)$. So, $Z(G)$ is a $p$-group. Since the center is abelian, then, by Cauchy's theorem, there exists an element of order $p$ and thus a subgroup of order $p$, say $N$. Since $N \subset Z(G)$, then $N$ is normal in $G$.

Consider $G/N$. Then $|G/N|=p^{r-1}$. By the induction hypothesis, there exists normal subgroups of order $p^i$ for $0\le i \le r-1$. By the correspondence theorem, these normal subgroups have the form $H_0/N, H_1/N, \dots, H_{r-1}/N$, where $H_i$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ containing $N$, and where $|H_i/N|=p^i$.

So, $|H_i|/|N|=p^i$ and thus $|H_i|=p^i|N|=p^ip=p^{i+1}$. So, there exists a normal subgroup of order $$|\{1\}|=p^0, |H_0|=p^1, |H_1|=p^2, \dots, |H_{r-1}|=p^r.$$

Comment: You don't really need the third iso. theorem. Immediately, $|H_i|=p^i|N|$.

Comment: Ahh, you're right. Edited. Thanks.

Comment: Good! Now you don't need to look elsewhere :)